# How to create random Probability matrix on js?

Tags: javascript, php

Such as:

```
probability_matrix(3)

return == >  
[0.2; 0.5; 0.3]    
[0.2; 0.3; 0.5]     
[0.6; 0.2; 0.2]
```

The sum of the elements in the rows and columns must be equal to one

Comment: What trouble are you facing? Have you tried anything?

Comment: The sum of the elements in the rows and columns must be equal to one

Comment: @TerenikDmitry Do you want negative numbers?

Comment: no, its must be Probability matrix

Comment: Should the numbers always be exactly one decimal place? Can they be 0.0 or 1.0?

Comment: It is necessary to generate a matrix of probability of occurrence of symbols of the alphabet (Conjugate probability matrix)
- - -
i think that they should not be zero or one

Answer (score 0):

my bad cod:

---

```
function generationMatrix(number) {
    var coefficient = 1 / number;
    var indexMass = Array(number);
    var matrix = Array(number);
    // Create an array with uniformly distributed mean values
    for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        indexMass[i] = i;
        var row = Array(number);
        for (var j = 0; j < number; j++) {
            row[j] = getRandom(coefficient / 2, coefficient);
        }
        matrix[i] = row;
    }
    // In (number-1) lines, we change the random element to such that the sum of the elements in the (row) is equl 1
    for (var i = 0; i < number - 1; i++) {
        var rand_index = indexMass.splice((Math.floor(Math.random() * indexMass.length)), 1);
        matrix[i].splice(rand_index, 1);
        var newElem = 1 - matrix[i].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
        matrix[i].splice(rand_index, 0, newElem);
    }
    // TReplace the remaining (row) with a (row) such that the sum of the elements in the columns is equl 1
    for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        var sum = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < number; j++) {
            if (j != indexMass[0])
                sum += matrix[i][j];
        }
        matrix[indexMass[0]][i] = 1 - sum;
    }
    return matrix;
}
```